# Get the column_Name if I know the column value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

My requirement is to compare data between two environments and i there is diff in both tables of both environments, insert that data to a temp table and display it.The above solution is not suiting for my scenario. I will explain my scenario in a better way.

In a Curor Cur1, I have all data of DEV from a Table(Report) where Rep_ID=1,    Getting corresponding data from the TEST of REPORT Table where Rep_ID=1 In a while loop I am comparing the data of DEV and TEST

```
if (@DevData1 <> @TestData1) 
   BEGIN Get ColumnName from Report table where @DevData1 =1 Insert Into #TempTable (ColumnName, DevData1, TestData1)
ENDS Cur1 Ends
```

When I try to get the column name for a varchar column, I am getting the column name properly with the below query

```
Declare @ColStrRep nvarchar(1000)= 'select @retValOut= Col.value(''local-name(.)'', ''varchar(max)'') from (select * from Rep_attr where Rep_Name = '''+@reptName +''' for xml path(''''), type) as T(XMLCol) cross apply T.XMLCol.nodes(''*'') as n(Col) where Col.value(''.'', ''varchar(100)'') = '+@reptName +'' 

print @ColStrRep 

EXEC Sp_executesql @ColStrRep,N'@retValOut nvarchar(100) out',@Column_Name OUT
```

But when I try to get the columnName for an integer column, and that too when we have the same value as 1 in the table( like RepID=1, Flag=1 , IsEmpty=1 etc), the query is getting confused and instead of Rep_ID, it retrieves the column IsEmpty. SO I need another query which just give me the columnname for a columnValue.

Thanks and Regards,
Sajitha

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What does "this query will not work" mean, exactly?   Please post your attempt and the error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.

But I could manage the situation with the below query.
In case, the column value is a varchar, then the below query gives me the column Name.

```
Declare @ColStrDesc  nvarchar(1000)= 'select 
                     @retValOut= Col.value(''local-name(.)'', ''varchar(max)'') 
                    from (select *
                          from Rep_attr
                          where Rep_Name = '''+@reptName +'''
                          for xml path(''''), type) as T(XMLCol)
                      cross apply 
                        T.XMLCol.nodes(''*'') as n(Col) 
                    where Col.value(''.'', ''varchar(100)'') = '''+@rep_Desc +''''
                    print @ColStrDesc
                     EXEC Sp_executesql @ColStrDesc,N'@retValOut nvarchar(100) out',@Column_Name OUT
```

In case, the column Value is an integer , thenn below query gives me column name.

```
Declare @ColErr  nvarchar(1000)= 'SELECT @retValOut= STUFF('''' 
  + CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Rep_attr] WHERE Cast([Rep_Errs] as VARCHAR(64)) = '+@rep_Errs+') THEN '' Rep_Errs'' ELSE '''' END , 1, 1, '''')'

                     EXEC Sp_executesql @ColErr,N'@retValOut nvarchar(100) out',@Column_Name OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will search using LIKE operator for varchar columns (i.e. column like '%5%') and a strict value for int columns (i.e. column=5)

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME = 'your_table',
        @search_string  VARCHAR(100) = '5', --what to search
        @column_name    SYSNAME,
        @type_name    SYSNAME,
        @sql_string     VARCHAR(2000)


BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE columns_cur CURSOR 
        FOR 
            SELECT columns.name, types.name type_name FROM sys.columns
                JOIN sys.types ON columns.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
                JOIN sys.objects ON columns.object_id=objects.object_id
                WHERE objects.type = 'U' AND objects.name=@table_name
                AND types.name IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar', 'int', 'bigint', 'smallint') --types of columns which you want to use for search

    OPEN columns_cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name, @type_name
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @type_name IN ( 'varchar', 'nvarchar')
            SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE [' + @column_name + '] LIKE ''%' + @search_string + '%'') RAISERROR(''' + @table_name + ', ' + @column_name + ''',0,1) WITH NOWAIT'
        ELSE
            SET @sql_string = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ' + @table_name + ' WHERE [' + @column_name + '] = TRY_CAST(''' + @search_string + ''' AS '+ @type_name +')) RAISERROR(''' + @table_name + ', ' + @column_name + ''',0,1) WITH NOWAIT'
        EXECUTE(@sql_string)

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cur INTO @column_name, @type_name
    END

    CLOSE columns_cur
    DEALLOCATE columns_cur
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    CLOSE columns_cur
    DEALLOCATE columns_cur
    RAISERROR(' - No access to table %s',0,1,@table_name) WITH NOWAIT
END CATCH
```